# Save notification in console on use REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

I'm using Firebase to send notification to devices. I'm following the specification of [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) as describe in firebase website. Everything is working fine.

I would like to know if it is possible to keep a copy of sent message in the console even sending them form REST API.

Taking a look in [server reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table1), I didn't find anything related with this. Actually is not a requirement, its only personal curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

There is no public API for the Notifications panel of the Firebase Console. That space is reserved for messages sent *from* that same console.